# This projects needs to be migrated?

Tags: migration, visual-studio-2012

I have a sharepoint 2010 solution. i migrated it to sp 2013, all sharepoint 2010 projects have been migrated without any problems. Office projects (Excel and outlook addins) however have been acting out.

i get "this project needs to be migrated" error.

what changes should i make to get Visual studio 2012 to open the project ??

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try to compare properties of smoothly migrated projects with properties of not migrated projects. 
For this - click on migrated project, right button click than choose Unload project - again right button click and choose Edit properties.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

At the very least VS2012 will update your solution file with lines like this:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
# Visual Studio 2012
```

As for the rest of your solution/projects, what gets "migrated" depends on a number of factors - if you have SP1 for VS2010 then you will have far better interoparebility between the two editions of VS. The big stand-out is database projects (.dbproj files become .sqlproj), regular class libraries should open fine in either edition.

Here is a quite comprehensive MSDN blog post discussing it: [Visual Studio 2012 New Features: Compatibility (aka Project Round-Tripping)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2012/06/05/visual-studio-2012-compatibility-aka-project-round-tripping.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Like Raf stated, you need to Edit the csproj file:

[image: Edit Version]

In the csproj file you only have to replace the "TargetOfficeVersion" Tag with your new Sharepoint Version (2016 would be 16.0):

[image: Edit Version]

After this change, the file has to be saved and then Reload Project to be clicked:

[image: Reload Project]

After this you maybe have to correct the references to point to the correct Microsoft.sharepoint.dll, but this depends on your configuration.